# .NET Eventhandler Management

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an event handler in code that I see is getting called multiple times when I am expecting it to only be called once.

In the past this has been because I have defined the delegation in the wrong place (so more that one delegate is added to the event handling list), but on this occastion this is only being set once (in the class constructor).

Rather than continuing to manually search through my code looking for errors, is there a (simple) pragmatic approach I can take to figuring out where event handlers are being assigned?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can replace the default:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

...with

```
private EventHandler _myEvent;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { _myEvent += value; }
    remove { _myEvent -= value; }
}
```

Then you could put logging or breakpoints inside the add/remove functions and look at the call stack.

Comment: That is a very simple and neat solution - works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using vb.net then are you sure that you are not adding the handler in a method and also using the handles keyword?

this causes an event to be handled twice.

Comment: Good idea, but again this focuses on manual searching. Also I'm using C#. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Resharper](http://jetbrains.com/), then right-click on your event and select "Find usages".

Comment: Would love to, but I don't have licence or budget for it :-(

Comment: I would say it pays for itself in about 1 month. I would never accept working without (or something similar) again.

Answer (score 1):

I have a code for it. Its 2 classes for help access to events

[Event Classes](http://rapidshare.com/files/250711091/CSoft.Core.zip)

And in my code introduce this:

[alt text http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1656/featurer.jpg](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1656/featurer.jpg)

Now you can debug events entering in

```
CSoft.Core.EventHelper.Raise();
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but Rogers idea of a customised accessor is really simple and works like a charm. Thanks for you input anyway. Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can change name (not using Visual Studio re-factoring tools, just simply change name in the code) and see where compiler breaks.